# Send this formjson with retrofit2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have this JSON body and I want to send it to server.

```
{
   "username" : "aa",
   "email" : "aa@email.com",
   "telephone" : 1234565165,
   "plainPassword" : {
      "first" : "aa",
      "second" : "aa"
   }
}
```

I use this entities :

User.java

```
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String username;
    private long telephone;
    private String email;
    private String image_name;
    private int activation;
    private int status;
    private String randomcode;

}
```

PlainPassword.java

```
public class PlainPassword {

    private String first;
    private String second;

}
```

My API interface class

```
@POST("registerREST")
Call<Object> addUser(@Body Object user);
```

And I use it like this:

```
Call<Object> call = services.addUser(u);

call.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {

    @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response) {

        if(response.isSuccessful()){

                LinkedTreeMap treemap = (LinkedTreeMap) response.body();
                RegisterResponse review = new RegisterResponse();
                double d = Double.parseDouble(treemap.get("userId").toString()) ;
                review.setUserId((int) d );

                    if(review.getUserId() == 0) {

                    } else {

                    }
                }
        }


        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {

        }

});
```

Answer (score 3):

The way you have to do it is:
Having two objects

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
private String username;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("telephone")
@Expose
private Integer telephone;
@SerializedName("plainPassword")
@Expose
private PlainPassword plainPassword;

public String getUsername() {
return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
this.username = username;
}

public String getEmail() {
return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
this.email = email;
}

public Integer getTelephone() {
return telephone;
}

public void setTelephone(Integer telephone) {
this.telephone = telephone;
}

public PlainPassword getPlainPassword() {
return plainPassword;
}

public void setPlainPassword(PlainPassword plainPassword) {
this.plainPassword = plainPassword;
}

}


import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class PlainPassword {

@SerializedName("first")
@Expose
private String first;
@SerializedName("second")
@Expose
private String second;

public String getFirst() {
return first;
}

public void setFirst(String first) {
this.first = first;
}

public String getSecond() {
return second;
}

public void setSecond(String second) {
this.second = second;
}

}
```

And then you need to send this in this format:

```
@POST("registerREST")
Call<ReturningObject> addUser(@Body Example user);
```

If you have more question about it, I invite you to check this website: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class test {

    public String username;
    public String email;
    public long telephone;
    public PlainPassword plainPassword;

public test(String username, String email, long telephone, PlainPassword plainPassword) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.telephone = telephone;
        this.plainPassword = plainPassword;
    }

    public class PlainPassword{


        public String first;
        public String second;


    }
}



use upper class for data post
```

after this

(your plainpass class)PlainPassword pp=new PlainPassword ("yourfirst","yoursecond');

(your main class name)test ta=new test("username","email","yourteliphonno",pp)

THEN CALL

Call call = services.addUser(ta);